# Windows 8 freezes up after ten minutes

Tags: windows-8, freeze, crash

Windows 8 keeps freezing up every ten minutes. I can't move my mouse, can't use the keyboard. <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd> does nothing. Once Windows 8 has frozen, only my physical power button works.

**Update**: The problem seems to occur when running Google Chrome.

Specs:

- Google Chrome Version 23.0.1271.52 beta-m
- Boot Camp 3.3
- Microsoft Windows 8 Pro 6.2.9200
- Apple MacBook Pro (MacBookPro5,5)

Comment: Its always ten minutes?

Comment: @soandos It varies, but it's about 5-10 minutes each time.

Comment: Are you overheating (speedfan to check)

Comment: @soandos No. My computer only freezes when running Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: Some Google Chrome extension or plugin was causing the system freeze. I uninstalled/disabled anything that had to do with video, thinking various ads and Flash content was to blame. Now I can use Chrome indefinitely without experience a freeze.

As a temporary workaround, use Internet Explorer or Firefox, or another nonChrome browser. Don't forget to change the default browser, or you can accidentally freeze your computer just by clicking a hyperlink in an unrelated program.

Comment: I also suspect it is something related to hidden updates being done by Chrome, since there are no other softwares consuming the CPU, you can see in task manager hidden processes (on Details tab) for Chrome, and each one is a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try and see if this works?

Open up a command prompt with administrator permissions. (You can do so with a right click on the command prompt application)

Then type in this command:

```
bcdedit /set disabledynamictick yes
```

Comment: This issue was fixed a while ago.

Comment: @SLaks What are you saying? Windows 8 is freezing up for me every ten minutes after I boot up. Obviously this was *not* fixed.

Comment: @mcandre You have all the latest updates installed then?

Comment: @JohnnyW Yes, Google Chrome and Windows 8 are up to date.

Comment: If it is update then this should be your version if you're on the dev channel: Version 24.0.1312.2 dev-m